# java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm: DESede or TripleDES required

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, 3des

I wrote this code, my key is: "ooWqEPcw7KR/h/JIbrFCRHiEVaybvnB2".

```
    try
    {
        Base64Decoder base64Decoder=new Base64Decoder();

        String encryptType="DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
        String workingKey="ooWqEPcw7KR/h/JIbrFCRHiEVaybvnB2";
        SecretKey secretKey=new SecretKeySpec(base64Decoder.decode(workingKey), encryptType);

        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance(encryptType);
        cipher.init(1, secretKey);
    }
    catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get this error!!!

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm: DESede or TripleDES required
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCrypt.init(DESedeCrypt.java:65)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.ElectronicCodeBook.init(ElectronicCodeBook.java:93)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:582)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:458)
    at  com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineInit(DESedeCipher.java:166)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:802)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:864)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1249)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1186)
    at EncryptText.main(EncryptText.java:24)
```

Comment: new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede"); **Note** using `1` intead of `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE` is not a good idea, use the constatnts.

Comment: I used from Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE but didn't work. Above code works in Android Studio. but it doesn't work in IntelliJIdea

Comment: Did you change `new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");` ?

Comment: Yessssssssss. Thanks. it works for me. You saved my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write SecretKeySpec as

```
SecretKey secretKey=new SecretKeySpec(base64Decoder.decode(workingKey),"DESede");
```

Also use `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE` and `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE` instead of constants.

Answer (score 2):

`DESedeCrypt` class supports only  `DESede` and `TripleDES` algorithms, as per source code:

```
void init(boolean decrypting, String algorithm, byte[] keys)
        throws InvalidKeyException {
    if (!algorithm.equalsIgnoreCase("DESede")
                && !algorithm.equalsIgnoreCase("TripleDES")) {
        throw new InvalidKeyException
            ("Wrong algorithm: DESede or TripleDES required");
    }
```

Your code has to use one of the two in the `SecretKey`. The `Cipher` can stay as `DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding`:

```
String workingKey = "ooWqEPcw7KR/h/JIbrFCRHiEVaybvnB2";
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(
        Base64.getDecoder().decode(workingKey), 
        "DESede");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(1, secretKey);
```